# Read in values from comma delimited text file and add,create object of the class, then add objects to collection

Tags: vb.net, list, object, text-files, streamreader

I currently have the following code:

```
Public Class CPUForm

    Dim myCPUList As New List(Of CPUClass)
    Dim Counter As Integer = 0

    Private Sub CPUForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog()

        Try
            If IO.File.Exists(OpenFileDialog.FileName) = False Then
            End If
        Catch ex As IO.FileNotFoundException
            MessageBox.Show("The File Could Not Be Found", "Alert")
        End Try
        If IO.File.Exists(OpenFileDialog.FileName) = True Then
            Dim sr As IO.StreamReader = IO.File.OpenText(OpenFileDialog.FileName)
            Dim line As Object
            Dim data() As Object
            Do Until sr.EndOfStream
                line = sr.ReadLine
                data = line.Split(",")
                Dim ACpu As New CPUClass(data(0), data(1), data(2), data(3), data(4), data(5))
                myCPUList(Counter) = ACpu
                Counter += 1
            Loop
            sr.Close()
        End If
        lstOut.DataSource = Nothing
        lstOut.DataSource = myCPUList
    End Sub
End Class
```

The goal here is to read-in values from a comma separated text file, create objects of the class, add those objects to the collection, and then display the collection in a listbox using an overridden ToString method.

Right now I get no errors, even at runtime. The problem is that one the file is selected, nothing happens. Nothing is displayed in the listbox as if nothing was added to the collection. Also, an overloaded constructor exists to receive the values being read in.

Comment: This is trivially simple using a CSV parsing tool like `CSVHelper`.  Be sure to add a `ToString()` override to your class

Comment: `myCPUList(Counter) = ACpu` This line should be throwing an exception since your list is empty and you are trying to reference an index position.  Use `myCPUList.Add(ACpu)` instead.

Comment: I've tried changing the line and still get the same result unfortunately.

Comment: Almost certainly you do get errors, or rather an error, but it is being swallowed because the code is in the `Load` event handler.  Wrap the entire contents of the event handler in a `Try` block and then display information from the actual exception caught to get more relevant info.

Comment: The only error I have seen is an out of memory exception.

Comment: ... or maybe the file you are selecting is empty.  You have to use the debugger to step through the code as it runs and examine the values.

Comment: I know for a fact the file is not empty.

Comment: You seem to want to ignore the debugger.

Comment: Do not compare `Boolean` values to `true` / `false` constants! Instead, simply use `If IO.File.Exists(...) Then` and `If Not IO.File.Exists(...) Then` respectively as these methods return already a `Boolean` value that could be checked on its own.

Comment: You are using `StreamReader` wrong... See this please https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.opentext(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: .Net has got a nice reader: Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser. No need to import anything.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the code is fine, the problem was an out of place comma in the text file.